# What is a "well behaved predicate" in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

The [SWI documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=testbody) mentions on several occasions "for well behaved predicates, leave no choicepoints." Can I take that to mean that, for "well behaved predicates" that are either deterministic or semideterministic, there should be no choicepoints left after an answer has been found? What is the definition of **well behaved predicate**? It's not in the [glossary](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=glossary).

I expect it to mean "works as it is expected to work", but I haven't found a clear well-defined definition.

For clarification:

This is the usage in the SWI-documentation:

- Deterministic predicates are predicates that must succeed exactly
  once and, for well behaved predicates, leave no choicepoints.

And this is the definition of deterministic predicates:

- Deterministic predicates are predicates that must succeed exactly once and leave no choicepoints.

`for well behaved predicates` is clearly intended to change the meaning of the definition somehow, why else add it?

PROBABLE ANSWER:

As @DanielLyons points out, the **well behaved** part likely means "works as expected" and in `plunit` this means that you have to pass flags such as `[nondet, fail]` to indicate how the tested predicate **should** behave. The predicate can work functionally, but give multiple solutions where a single one is expected and vice versa, which then no longer matches the flagged, expected behavior and generates warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the occurrences of this construction I see are in the plunit documentation, and refer to deterministic or semi-deterministic (single solution or 0/1 solutions) predicates. The implication here seems to be that you could call a predicate deterministic if it produces a single solution and leaves a choice-point (so you get exactly one successful unification but possibly more attempts that will definitely fail). It's the same story with semi-deterministic predicates (but probably only in the case where they have found their single success).

I don't think this is a well-defined term. It is always preferable that predicates which produce a single result should not leave choice points around unnecessarily, but perhaps plunit depends on this behavior for some reason and it's simply warning you of it. Prolog has no way of really knowing or keeping track of whether your predicate is deterministic. Other languages, especially Mercury, can. But the distinction here seems to be something plunit cares about, probably to avoid producing a spurious error message about a failed test or something.

Comment: Right? They use it to explain the expected behavior of plunit as if it's obvious what **well behaved** means in this context. From the context I extract that they take it to mean "Predicates that **should** return a single result without leaving choice points are expected to do this. Predicates that **should** return a single result while leaving choice points are expected to do this". They are using the meaning of the term to explain what the term means, and defining terms in terms of themselves is just not done logically, not even when explaining infinite recursion. It adds nothing?

Comment: @G_V I agree, it adds nothing. But sometimes when documenting code, one feels compelled to add words :)